# JsPDF Vuejs - is it possible to create a custom template?

Tags: vue.js, jspdf

In our application, we have export pdf and will try this jSPDF that I saw in the internet. Is it possible to use custom template for this? For example I have a created custom page then want it to use it in my jsPDF.

**Vue**

```html
<a class="btn btn-warning export-pdf" title="Export PDF" target="_blank" 
   @click="exportPDF()" ref="export_pdf">
  <i style="color: blue;" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
</a>
```

```js
method {        
  exportPDF(){
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10);
    doc.save('a4.pdf');
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add JsPDF (instructions of npm/yarn in [github](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)) as your dependency. With some import stuffs and there,then you should be able to create your custom/own Component with your template (many ways to pass data e.g props)

Hope helps

Comment: For example I import my custom vue for my export pdf how can I pass it in jsdPDF?

Comment: As far as i understand, jsdPDF will do 1) add text contents 2) save as pdf with the name u assigned, so as custom button click.
Props should be suffice for this, so your component can get values from props and called in method
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html